# How do I get Ubuntu desktop audio related packages

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I installed Ubuntu desktop 16.04.3 on my laptop and wiped out ubuntu desktop using tasksel. I installed alsa to have my sound work but I hear nothing. I can see my soundcard in alsamixer. I guess I can solve the problem if I install sound related packages included in ubuntu desktop because when I touched nothing from pure ubuntu desktop, I can get my sound. So is there way I can get sound related packages in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install PulseAudio:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

The restart or reload alsa:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```